# Non-interactive customization of FreeBSD ports AND saving config to /var/db/ports/*/options

Tags: freebsd

**Context:** I am writing an Ansible module allowing the non-interactive setting of options.

**Problem:** a non-interactive

```
make install clean OPTIONS_UNSET=SYSTEM_SCREENRC BATCH=YES
```

does not store the ports options.

**Desired outcome:** When doing a manual portupgrade I would like the system to know of the already chosen options (from eg. `/var/db/ports/sysutils_screen/options`. And not having to run all of ansible over the machine again.

**Question:** Do you know of a solution on how to achieve this?

**PS:** I tried using `portinstall --make-args` but could not pass any configuration arguments. Either I did not get it or it is/was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I have come is to pass the options to the config menu by using something like:

```
make config www_nginx_SET_FORCE="DSO DEBUG" www_nginx_UNSET_FORCE="IPV6"
```

To find the ports options name you can use:

```
make -V OPTIONS_NAME
```

Problem is then trying to save the config with the defined options, I have tried using `BATCH=yes` but can't bypass it.

Comment: thank you @nbari. I will try it on Monday in the office. it seems it is as close as my current outlined solution. I am just using the `OPTIONS_UNSET` / `OPTIONS_SET` variables taken from the makefiles...

Comment: Thanks it works non-interactive like this! `echo > make config sysutils_screen_UNSET_FORCE="SYSTEM_SCREENRC"` and it writes the configuration options out to the options file

Comment: @DanielW. how are you saving the options?

Comment: They are automatically writen out to `/var/db/ports/sysutils_screen/options` by make config!

Comment: I was mistaken. They are not written out when using the `echo >`. I had an old file still laying arround... I will try to use _expect_ or so and let you know